# Get all possible combinations of list of length 12 where 10 values must remain in sequential order, but two values can be at any index

Tags: python, list, combinations, python-itertools

For example:

```
var1 = 'cat'
var2 = 'dog'
starting_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

def getCombinations(var1, var2, starting_list):
   #code
   returns(combination_lists)
```

example returns:

```
combination_1 = ['cat','dog',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
combination_2 = ['cat',1,'dog',2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
combination_3 = [1,'cat','dog',2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
...
```

I assume this can probably be done using itertools python library but i cant seem to figure it out

I have tried programmatically looping through all possible combinations but I'm not sure how to be sure I am getting all combinations.

Comment: Shall cat always come before dog?

Answer (score 2):

You actually want the permutations of all possible indices in the list where you can put `"cat"` and `"dog"`. Then, you want to select one of the two `var` variables, or the next available element from `starting_list` as you iterate over `range(len(starting _list)+2)`. In the following code, I first populate the list with `None` as the placeholder for all `var*` values, and then replace them with the appropriate values.

```
import itertools as it

def getCombinations(var1, var2, starting_list):
    N = len(starting_list)+2
    v_pos_perms = it.permutations(range(N), 2)
    for v_pos in v_pos_perms:
        st_iter = iter(starting_list)
        lst = [None if i in v_pos 
               else next(st_iter)
               for i in range(N)]
        lst[v_pos[0]] = var1
        lst[v_pos[1]] = var2
        yield lst


var1 = 'cat'
var2 = 'dog'
starting_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for l in getCombinations(var1, var2, starting_list):
    print(l)
```

Which gives your desired output:
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##lVFLasMwEN3rFLOLTYcSK/1DV937AsYYtR67Alky0jQ0p3clJTFJ6aazEBreF2k@8Kezu2XR0@w8g2by7JwJoEJchOhpgJH4zU3v2irWzoZir3yFEE@JEFh51nbsjA5cvgiIU8MrGLLFNXYjM7jvZhe6mfwUIk3zbbp@8cnaKztSUZcIssz0wfmjBLS91B6T0gTuUutsRv5X6MoygSOjqZ0l0APo1Q7IBAJL31ycnMocmhnnOu2lT5N1zbZto2N6iz/A6gzKFTxoMn2iCCGSKuKbD8WbtMi09G7ciKv6qXGFEnd4h/f4gI/4hM9YbVshUkWTKv73c2avLRemXJYf)

```
['cat', 'dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
['cat', 1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
['cat', 1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
['cat', 1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
['cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
['cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
['cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10]
['cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10]
['cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10]
['cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10]
['cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog']
['dog', 'cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'cat', 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'cat', 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'cat', 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10]
[1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10]
[1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog']
['dog', 1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'dog', 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'cat', 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'cat', 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10]
[1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog']
['dog', 1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'dog', 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'dog', 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'cat', 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog']
['dog', 1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'dog', 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'dog', 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'dog', 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog']
['dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog']
['dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog']
['dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 'dog', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 'dog', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 'dog', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10, 'dog']
['dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 'cat', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 'dog', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 'dog', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10, 'dog']
['dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10]
[1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 'cat', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 'cat', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 'dog', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10, 'dog']
['dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10]
[1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10]
[1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 'cat', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 'cat', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 'cat', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat', 'dog']
['dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat']
[1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat']
[1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat']
[1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10, 'cat']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10, 'cat']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10, 'cat']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog', 'cat']
```

---

A more general approach that supports any number of `var*` values by replacing them with a list of possible values:

```
def getCombinations(all_vars, starting_list):
    N = len(starting_list)+len(all_vars)
    v_pos_perms = it.permutations(range(N), 2)
    for v_pos in v_pos_perms:
        st_iter = iter(starting_list)
        lst = [None if i in v_pos 
               else next(st_iter)
               for i in range(N)]
        for vp, val in zip(v_pos, all_vars):
            lst[vp] = val

        yield lst
```

If you really need to return a list containing all these lists, you can define a `result=[]` at the start of the function and append to it instead of yielding, then `return result` at the end, but I prefer yielding in situations where the function can return a large result, because that way you only calculate subsequent elements of your result on demand.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example with just simple loops. For each index value of i, iterate through all index values of j.
The return of the function is a list of lists.

This gives all possible combinations around the index of the two vars while keeping the existing list untouched.

At every loop, the new indexes are changed, but the original list is always the same.

This is better than using iterate tools as you don't depend on importing anything.

CODE:

```
def getCombinations(var1, var2, starting_list):
    end_list=starting_list.copy()
    combination_lists=[]
    for i in range(0,len(end_list)+2):
        for j in range(0,len(end_list)+1):
            end_list.insert(j, var2)
            end_list.insert(i, var1)        
            print(end_list)
            combination_lists.append(end_list)
            end_list=starting_list.copy()
    return(combination_lists)

var1 = 'cat'
var2 = 'dog'
starting_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]


listfinal=getCombinations(var1, var2, starting_list)
print('FINAL RESULT IS A TOTAL OF ' + str(len(listfinal)) + ' LISTS.')
print(listfinal)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['cat', 'dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
['cat', 1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
['cat', 1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
['cat', 1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
['cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
['cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
['cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10]
['cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10]
['cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10]
['cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10]
['cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog']
['dog', 'cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'cat', 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'cat', 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'cat', 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10]
[1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10]
[1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog']
['dog', 1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'dog', 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'cat', 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'cat', 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10]
[1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog']
['dog', 1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'dog', 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'dog', 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'cat', 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog']
['dog', 1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'dog', 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'dog', 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'dog', 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog']
['dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog']
['dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog']
['dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 'dog', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 'dog', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 'dog', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10, 'dog']
['dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 'cat', 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 'dog', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 'dog', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10, 'dog']
['dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10]
[1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 'cat', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 'cat', 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 'dog', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10, 'dog']
['dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10]
[1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10]
[1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 'cat', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 'cat', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 'cat', 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat', 'dog']
['dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat']
[1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat']
[1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat']
[1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10, 'cat']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10, 'cat']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10, 'cat']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog', 'cat']
FINAL RESULT IS A TOTAL OF 132 LISTS.
[['cat', 'dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], ['cat', 1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], ['cat', 1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], ['cat', 1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], ['cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], ['cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], ['cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10], ['cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10], ['cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10], ['cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10], ['cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog'], ['dog', 'cat', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 'cat', 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 'cat', 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 'cat', 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10], [1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10], [1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10], [1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog'], ['dog', 1, 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 'dog', 'cat', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 'cat', 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 'cat', 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10], [1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10], [1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog'], ['dog', 1, 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 'dog', 2, 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 'dog', 'cat', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 'cat', 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10], [1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog'], ['dog', 1, 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 'dog', 2, 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 'dog', 3, 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 'dog', 'cat', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog'], ['dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 'cat', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog'], ['dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 'cat', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog'], ['dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 'cat', 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 'dog', 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 'dog', 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 'dog', 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10, 'dog'], ['dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10], [1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 'cat', 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 'cat', 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 'dog', 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 'dog', 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10, 'dog'], ['dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10], [1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10], [1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 'cat', 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 'cat', 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 'cat', 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 'dog', 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10, 'dog'], ['dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10], [1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10], [1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10], [1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 'cat', 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 'cat', 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 'cat', 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 'cat', 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat', 'dog'], ['dog', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat'], [1, 'dog', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat'], [1, 2, 'dog', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat'], [1, 2, 3, 'dog', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 'dog', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'dog', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'dog', 7, 8, 9, 10, 'cat'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'dog', 8, 9, 10, 'cat'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'dog', 9, 10, 'cat'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'dog', 10, 'cat'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'dog', 'cat']]
```

Comment: An explanation of your code would be nice.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I have added the explanation.

Comment: Thank you. Re. _"This is better than using iterate tools as you don't depend on importing anything."_: I disagree. You could make this argument if the library was something like `numpy` or `pandas`, but `itertools` is part of the standard library and very much part of the python language. Reinventing the wheel just for the sake of it isn't a great idea

Comment: I am not reinventing the wheel. I am actually using the oldest wheel, without bells and whistles. My code is just built from some snippets of code that I found on Google and pasted them together with some logic. So you can imagine I am not competing about it. Anyways you still were not able to convince me that iterate tools is better in this case, could you please elaborate for my learning? And thank you for your opinion. I am glad to have your attention as from your code I believe you are generally a much more experienced programmer than me. Bye.

Comment: This is a good approach! Helped my fundamental understanding of it.